# Filtering Frequency Peaks of Sound File

Tags: 555, sound, band-pass

I'm looking into using a 7 second long .wav sound file, and turning on an LED for 0.5s once a 500 Hz peak is detected. I have looked into several methods on how to achieve this. My main idea was to use a bandpass-filter to primarily only let through the desired peaks, and then run it through a 555 timer in order to turn on an LED for the respective amount of time.

The issue that I have come across is that one filter is simply not enough in order to fully filter the signals I'm working with. I'm aware of the fact that I could cascade the bandpass filters but it still doesn't feel like a robust and smart solution to this problem. How would I approach this problem? Is there something obvious I'm not noticing?

Comment: What order bandpass did you try ? The higher the order, the better the frequency selectivity,

Comment: 1st order, I don't have the materials to build a higher order filter at the moment, another issue is that the 555 timer requires a 4.5-5V input, which is hard to meet with any circuit really.

Comment: wait, but you have the digital file, why don't you just do all this in digital domain?

Comment: @Hilmar But then the settling time will take a while, and the repetitive peaks until it decays that can false trigger. I'd propose a locked-in amplifier, or the sorts, since it's only for one frequency. The filtering could be a basic moving average since the frequency is fixed, so the response will be 2 ms fast.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue that I have come across is that one filter is simply not enough in order to fully filter the signals I'm working with. I'm aware of the fact that I could cascade the bandpass filters but it still doesn't feel like a robust and smart solution to this problem

There's higher order filters, active filters, which are *not* just cascaded bandpasses, which would perform better. Analog Devices has a pretty neat [Analog Filter Design Wizard](https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/).

But honestly, I think the "modern" solution to this is

1. low pass filter to something well above 500 Hz, say 750 Hz; a simple RC might do. All that needs to happen is that at 1.25 kHz + 500 Hz, there's plenty of suppression.
2. use an ADC, typically the one built into your microcontroller to sample that at a sufficient, but very low rate, say 2.5 kHz
3. Implement the detection as a digital filter – for example,  10 taps of IIR would easily give you a filter response like this (\$f_s=2.5\,\text{kHz}\$, \$f_\text{stop, low}=450\,\text{Hz}\$, \$f_\text{c1utoff, low}=475\,\text{Hz},\$ \$f_\text{cutoff,high}=525\,\text{Hz},\$ \$f_\text{stop, high}=550\,\text{Hz}\$, \$A_\text{stopband}=-46\,\text{dB}\$, Chebyshev Type 1 filter (thinking about it, Cheby type 2 might have been wiser, or even just straightforward Bessel design... hm.)):
   [image: Magnitude and Phase response]
   Being less than 20 multiply-add per sample, i.e., less than 50.000 multiplications a second, will bore any modern microntroller with a floating point unit.
4. After the filter, ignore 4 out of 5 samples, (i.e.,decimate by 5)
5. low-pass filter again (this can really be something extremely cheap, e.g a moving average) to say, 10 Hz, decimate again if you want,
6. square your sample stream: you get a stream of output power.
7. Write a software "debouncer" for powers above a threshold
8. turn on your LED if you get high power for long enough

**FAQ**

- **Is that filter stable?** Depends on how you ask. Yes, all poles are inside the unit circle:
  [image: Pole/Zero plot]
  But that is for an infinite-bitdepth implementation. The feedforward coefficients are pretty small, but contribute to stability, so if you quantize, your results might be different.
  Doesn't matter, though, because it will still only be unstable if you happen to hit a frequency you want to detect, and nothing stops you from resetting your filter state once you've detected.
- **How did you design that?** [PyFDA](https://github.com/chipmuenk/pyfda) is a cool tool. You can simply install it using `pip3 install --user pyfda` and run it as `pyfdax`. Specs for this filter as above.
- **But there's a large group delay! Up to 0.1 s!** The amount of group delay is inherently linked to the steepness of your transition from stop- to passband (and vice versa). It's the basic time/frequency uncertainty! (the same thing behind Heisenberg uncertainty, btw.) No analog or digital filter that can beat that. Physics/math is unrelenting!